# React router v6 is not rendring the component

Tags: reactjs

I have a different design for my login page and admin panel but when I login into the application my admin panel routes aren't rendering the component.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ScrollToTop>
                <AuthContextProvider>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/app" exact element={<App/>} />
                        <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
                    </Routes>
                </AuthContextProvider>
            </ScrollToTop>
        </BrowserRouter>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );

app.js

    return (
        <div className={wrapperClass} onClick={onWrapperClick}>
            <Tooltip ref={copyTooltipRef} target=".block-action-copy" position="bottom" content="Copied to clipboard" event="focus" />

            <AppTopbar onToggleMenuClick={onToggleMenuClick} layoutColorMode={'dark'}
                mobileTopbarMenuActive={mobileTopbarMenuActive} onMobileTopbarMenuClick={onMobileTopbarMenuClick} onMobileSubTopbarMenuClick={onMobileSubTopbarMenuClick} />
            <div className="layout-sidebar" style={{ background: "#232531" }} onClick={onSidebarClick}>
                <AppMenu model={menu} onMenuItemClick={onMenuItemClick} layoutColorMode={layoutColorMode} />
            </div>
            <div className="layout-main-container">
                <div className="layout-main">
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" exact element={<Dashboard colorMode={layoutColorMode} location={location} />} />
                        <Route path="/customers" element={<Contacts/>} />
                        <Route path="/customers/new" element={<AddContact/>} />
                        <Route path="/customers/:id" element={<CustomerCard/>} />
                    </Routes>
                </div>
                <AppFooter layoutColorMode={layoutColorMode} />
            </div>
            <CSSTransition classNames="layout-mask" timeout={{ enter: 200, exit: 200 }} in={mobileMenuActive} unmountOnExit>
                <div className="layout-mask p-component-overlay"></div>
            </CSSTransition>
        </div>
);
```

My login and dashboard routes are working but when I navigate to other components they are not rendering. What is the problem?

Comment: I hope you've defined the `Outlet` properly?

Answer (score 0):

In a normal react programm the app component is wrapped inside of the index-js for the render this seems to be missing here, if this is accidental just add the app-js to the index, if not then add the browser router property around the app.js. All route and router elements must be childs of the browser router

Also check your outlet that you seem to use for the routes, this isnt provided here but it could lead to issues that arent covered here

**Example for the app js in the code**

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <ScrollToTop>
            <AuthContextProvider>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/app" exact element={<App/>} />
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
               <App />
               </Routes>
            </AuthContextProvider>
        </ScrollToTop>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```